# libGL error while running Steam

Tags: 16.04, drivers, steam

I'm trying to run Steam, but the console is throwing this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your AMD drivers are either not up to date or not installed. Install `glmark2` with `sudo apt install glmark2` and then run it with `glmark2`. Post the output of glmark2 to your question. (By the way, you should put the output of commands as code to define that it is code.)